# How to avoid updating original array after using $filter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Please see below code:

```js
var fieldsControls = $filter('filter')(vm.FieldsControls, { FieldId: id });

            for (var i = 0; i < fieldsControls.length; i++)
            {
                if (fieldsControls[i].ControlType == "DropDown") {
                    fieldsControls[i].Options = $filter('filter')(vm.Options, { type: fieldsControls[i].type });
                }
            }
            return fieldsControls;
```

After return (or even after the for loop) I observed that the original array "vm.FieldsControls" is getting updated with new Options value. However, shouldn't this just change new array fieldControls only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prepare deep copy of you array first. Here is the code:

```
     var copy = angular.copy(vm.FieldsControls);

     var fieldsControls = $filter('filter')(copy, { FieldId: id });

        for (var i = 0; i < fieldsControls.length; i++)
        {
            if (fieldsControls[i].ControlType == "DropDown") {
                fieldsControls[i].Options = $filter('filter')(vm.Options, { type: fieldsControls[i].type });
            }
        }
        return fieldsControls;
```

Comment: I tried it, but it gives error as "fieldsControls  is undefined".

Comment: Sorry, I used old syntax. this is as it should be: var copy = angular.copy(vm.FieldsControls); @TechTurtle